# Express.js custom template engine (plate)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, template-engine

I am trying to get plate template engine to work with express.js.  My initial attempt was this:

```
app.register('.html', {
    compile: function (str, options) {
        var template = new plate.Template(str);
        return function(locals) {
            return template.render(locals, function(err, data) {
                return data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I see that the problem is that template.render doesn't return anything (undefined) but passes the data to a callback.  I'm not sure how to make it work in this case as Express expects the compile function to return a function that directly returns a rendered template when called.

I was thinking perhaps I can use promises to solve this issue but had no success there either since the express code doesn't expect a promise to be returned.  Im not too up to speed on promises so I may just be doing it wrong:

```
app.register('.html', {
    compile: function (str, options) {
        var promise = new Promise();
        var template = new plate.Template(str);
        return function(locals) {
            template.render(locals, function(err, data) {
                promise.resolve(data);
            });
            return promise;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is an example of a custom implementation that does works.  The difference is that underscore templates template() function directly returns the rendered string like so:

```
app.register('.html', {
    compile: function (str, options) {
        var template = _.template(str);
        return function (locals) {
            return template(locals);
        };
    }
});
```

I'd really like to use Plate templates since the {% block %} tag is so awesome.  Any help is appreciated.

pertinent documentation:

[plate's github docs](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/plate)

[express.js app.register docs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app.register())

Comment: The creator of plate promptly added a patch to the project to make it compatible with express after I asked this.  plate@0.0.13+ has the change and you can see implementation details [here](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/plate/wiki/Getting-Started---In-Node)

Comment: You should add an answer to this question and then accept it if that's true!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The creator of plate promptly added a patch to the project to make it compatible with express after I asked this. plate@0.0.13+ has the change and you can see implementation details [here](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/plate/wiki/Getting-Started---In-Node)