# How to configure Bliss Templating in express js?

Tags: node.js, express

I was trying what I've seen in other questions with no luck:

- [Express.js custom template engine (plate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886678/express-js-custom-template-engine-plate)
- [node.js + express.js + dust.js issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734555/node-js-express-js-dust-js-issues)

I tried to override the default engine configuration with

```
app.register('.js.html', {
    compiler: function(str,options){...}
});
```

but register is undefined in express js.

I got Bliss working this way

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    //res.render('index', {});
    res.send(bliss.render(__dirname+"/index",{}));
};
```

but I'd like to use res.render('index',output) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set it up this way:

```
var Bliss = new require('bliss');
var bliss = new Bliss();
app.engine('.bliss',function(path,options,fn){
    fn(null,bliss.render(path, options));
});
```

Then you call it like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('user.bliss', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

You need a file called user.bliss under the views directory

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this in my app:

```
var Bliss = require('bliss');
var bliss = new Bliss();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send(bliss.render('./app/views/layout','title'));
});
```